# Prepared statement with SELECT returns 0

Tags: java, sql

I've created this method to choose the id from an artist using his name, but it returns 0.

```
public int getIdArtist(){

    Conexion connection=new Conexion();
    ArtistVO artistVO=new ArtistVO();
    int id=0;

    try{
        String cSql="SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlArtistId=connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(cSql);
        sqlArtistId.setString(1, artistVO.getNameArtist());
        ResultSet result=sqlArtistId.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(id); //debug
        while(result.next()){
            id=result.getInt("ArtistId");
        }
        return id;
    }catch(SQLException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've tried with some prints to check where it fails, and it fails right after `executeQuery()`; any idea why this is happening?

```
public class ArtistVO {

private int idArtist;
private String nameArtist;

public int getIdArtist(){
    return idArtist;
}

public void setIdArtist(int idArtist){
    this.idArtist=idArtist;
}

public String getNameArtist(){
    return nameArtist;
}

public void setNameArtist(String nameArtist){
    this.nombreArtist=nombreArtist;
}
}
```

This is part of the code where I set the name of the artist, the rest of the method is irrelevant:

```
            String nameArtist=chooseArtist.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println(nameArtist); //debug
            artistVO.setNameArtist(nameArtist);
```

It takes the name from a Combobox and using the print it shows the name, show, setting and getting the name isn't the issue.

**#2: UPDATE**

This method is for adding an Album, `sqlAddAlbum.setInt(3, getIdArtist());` should take the id given in `getIdArtist`but according to you first update, it is underlined in red and I don't know how to adjust it:

```
    public void addAlbum(AlbumVO albumVO){

    Conexion connection=new Conexion();

    try{
        String cSql="INSERT into album values(?,?) where ArtistId=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlAddAlbum=connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
        sqlAddAlbum.setInt(1, getMaxIdAlbum());
        sqlAddAlbum.setString(2, albumVO.getNameAlbum());
        sqlAddAlbum.setInt(3, getIdArtist());
        Integer affectedRows=sqlAddAlbum.executeUpdate();

        if(affectedRows>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Album has been inserted","Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Album has not been inserted", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        sqlAddAlbum.close();
        connection.closeConnection();
    }catch(SQLException exception){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Album could not be added", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Last update from @Rafael Osipov takes

```
     String nameArtist=chooseArtist.getSelectedItem().toString();
     int artistId = getIdArtist(nameArtist);
     System.out.println("artistId = " + artistId);
```

I pasted that code to show how I get the name of the artist from a Combobox, it doesn't need to be changed or adjusted, the print line is a debug line so no changes needed either.

Like I've said the issue is in `addAlbum()` because with the first change you made to `getIdArtist()` it underlines in red the call to this method, and I don't know how to solve it, I hope I made myself clear now.

Comment: I checked exception, and it's because it's returns a 0, therefore the insert sentence I'm using with this query tries to insert a value in an ID 0; so the mistake must be here.

`ArtisVO` isn't empty, in another method I set the name using `setArtistName()` and it returns name correctly.

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line:

```
ArtistVO artistVO=new ArtistVO();
```

You are creating a new object by class `ArtistV0`. Since we don't have the code for this class I assume this object is empty inside, and there is no artist name set upon the creation of the object.

When you call:

```
artistVO.getNameArtist()
```

on the just created object, you get an empty string and your sql looks like that:

```
SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=''
```

And when you execute your sql you do not get a record where artist's name is empty, because there's no such record in your `artist` table.

---

**UPDATE**

Please look at your `getIdArtist()` method. Even you have chosen artist name outside of this method, you don't use this chosen artist name inside of this method. You are creating a new object inside of this method, and this object has empty artist name.

Pass **external and populated** `ArtistVO` object to this method as a parameter and use it:

```
public int getIdArtist(ArtistVO artistVO){

    Conexion connection=new Conexion();
    int id=0;

    try{
        String cSql="SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlArtistId=connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(cSql);
        sqlArtistId.setString(1, artistVO.getNameArtist());
        ResultSet result=sqlArtistId.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(id); //debug
        while(result.next()){
            id=result.getInt("ArtistId");
        }
        return id;
    }catch(SQLException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

Please note that java statements are case sensitive. I am not sure what `chooseArtist.getSelectedItem()` returns, so I've updated your method again.

Check the code below.

Declare `getIdArtist()` in a new way:

```
public int getIdArtist(String artistName){

    Conexion connection=new Conexion();
    int id=0;

    try{
        String cSql="SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlArtistId=connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(cSql);
        sqlArtistId.setString(1, artistName);
        ResultSet result=sqlArtistId.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(id); //debug
        while(result.next()){
            id=result.getInt("ArtistId");
        }
        return id;
    }catch(SQLException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To use this method in your code:

```
String nameArtist=chooseArtist.getSelectedItem().toString();
int artistId = getIdArtist(nameArtist);
System.out.println("artistId = " + artistId);
```

Comment: @NeoChiri Please show your `artist` table contents.

Comment: @NeoChiri Also, please look at the `getIdArtist()` method again. Inside of this method you **don't set** the artist name. Inside of this method artist name is empty. Maybe, outside of this method you have chosen the artist name and set it to another object, but inside of this method you are creating a new object with empty artist name. Pass artist object as a parameter to `getIdArtist` and use this parameter object instead of new object you are creating inside of this method.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right, now, I don't have any idea how to set ArtistName using the name that I get from the Combobox on another class.

Comment: @NeoChiri In my update I've posted updated version of your method. Change it as I advised, and call it, using populated object. It should work ok.

Comment: I did what you pasted, but now I updated my code, the method which uses `getNameAlbum()` underlines this call in red, I tried to write `ArtistaVO` between `()` and it's still underlined...

Comment: I updated my post, look below **#2:UPDATE** I explain which my issue is much better.
I really appreciate your help and I'm so sorry for being such pain... I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: @NeoChiri you are calling `sqlAddAlbum.setInt(3, getIdArtist());`. Note that your call `getIdArtist()` does not have a parameter. According to my update it **should have a string parameter**, that contains the name of an artist. If your album object contains artist name, get it from this album object to pass to `getIdArtist` call, or add additional string parameter with artist name to `addAlbum` method.